# Accessing a list with only recursion and lambdas

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, lambda

As part of my homework I have to access every element o a list without a for loop to use it in a function I'm allowed to use, e.g:

```
myList=['Hello','World']
```

I've tried using lambda functions (Because I'm not allowed to declare functions with Def) but didn't work.

```
function(next(myList))
```

Also tried using next(myList) but sometimes the list can have 1000+ elements.

Comment: Can you use a `while` loop and a counter (or `next`) (terrible practice, but it works)? Not sure what the point of this assignment is, but I guess that's the educational system these days.

Comment: What do you mean by `to access`? `myList.copy()` technically "accesses" each element. Do you need to do something with each element? Have you considered a list comprehension or is that still considered a `for` loop.

Comment: `it = iter(my_list); print(next(it)); print(next(it))`

Comment: I never understood why any sane instructor would ask for something like this.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq the last line says `the list can have 1000+ elements.` That will be a lot of `print()` statements.

Comment: @MarkMeyer `eval("print(next(it)); " * 1000)` ;)

Comment: @MateenUlhaq yuck - the hurts :)

Comment: we're using a functional paradigm and the idea is to learn the uses of recursion so I'm not allowed to use any for or while loop.

Comment: I need to access every element of the list so I can give it to a function (that I'm allowed to use)

Comment: You should mention the purpose of the exercise and that you are allowed to use recursion in the question. That makes a sea of difference.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://www.onelinerizer.com/

Comment: ...but you're not allowed to declare functions? So you need to use recursion and a lambda?

Comment: `it = iter([1, 2, 3]); f = lambda _=None: f(print(next(it))); f()`. I leave it to you to figure out how to avoid the exception at the end. If you're not even allowed to *name* functions (e.g. `f = ...`), you will probably need a [Y-combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed-point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus).

Comment: practically `list(map(lambda x : x, myList))` accesses all elements, since `map` function iterates through elements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda with map for apply a function to each element:

```
myList=['Hello','World']

list(map(lambda x: x.upper(), myList))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using map is the shortest way to do it. You don't need lambda.

```
li = list(range(10)) # this is your list
list(map(print, li)) # view each element
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### If you can use function you can use that trick

You can use recursion to access all elements.

At first create a function to read first element and delete that element.

Use that function again and again until the list is empty.

```
def show(my_list):
   try:
      print(my_list[0])
      del my_list[0]
      show(my_list)
   except:
      pass
```

Or if you want to do some action

```
new = []
def action(my_list):
   try:
      x = do_something(my_list[0])
      del my_list[0]
      new.append(x)
      action(my_list)
   except:
      pass
```

Here `do_something(data)` is your custom function.

Comment: I think this is too long way to do this.

Comment: But using this you can understand how things works Internally.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cleanest way to do this is with a `map` function:

```py
l = [1,2,3]
list(map(lambda x : print(x), l))
# returns
# >> 1
# >> 2
# >> 3
```